# C: Swap function with 3 arguments

Tags: arguments, swap

I have a little question that is giving me and headache. What I need to do is reading a .txt file which has shuffled random numbers, save them into an array, and print them to the screen sortted (with bubble sort).
The first 2 phases seem to be fine, the problem is that it looks like I'm missing something on my swap function and/or print line. The code I have atm is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


void swap(int A, int j, j+1)
{
    int original_A_i = A[j];
    A[j] = A[j+1];
    A[j+1] = original_A_i;
}

bool greater(double first, double second)
{
    return first > second;
}



int main()
{

    int totalNums = 0;
    double A[totalNums];
    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen ("file.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%lf", &A[i]) != EOF) {
        i++; }

    totalNums = i;

     fclose(fp);


    for (int i = 0; i < totalNums - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalNums - 1; j++) {
            if (greater(A[j], A[j + 1]))
                swap(A, j, j+1);
        }
    }

    printf("Ordem Ascendente:\n");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < totalNums ; i++ ) {
        printf("\n%lf", A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The errors I'm getting from messing around with the code are either a crash or a "0 0 0 0 0 0 0" result (separated by lines).
Note: The teacher wants us to try making this without using pointers, however, if we don't manage to get it working otherwise, we can use them with a lower grade.

PS: Go easy on me, I'm still learning and the problem here is probably something really simple :P

thanks in advance

Comment: @Shan, thanks for your reply, I made the changes you said but I'm still getting the following errors: 

|6|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'j'
|40|warning: implicit declaration of function 'swap' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|

Obs: line 6 is the swap function line, and like 40 is where I call the swap function (before the first printf)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing array right?  Then the swap def must be like this

```
 void swap(int A[], int j, j+1) {
     int original_A_i = A[j];
     A[j] = A[j+1];
     A[j+1] = original_A_i; }
```

If you are new to c check this [passing array](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm)